# Given a line segment from one vertex of a triangle to its opposite side, how to find the point of intersection with this internal line?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

Given the triangle in this diagram, if I draw a line segment (shown in blue) from vertex A to any location on line segment BC, the point of intersection with line segment BC will be at some percentage along the path from vertices B to C.

If I know this percentage along the path from B to C where the blue line intersects line segment BC, how do I calculate the percentage along the path from B to D where the blue line intersects that path? I believe this is a function of three angles: θ, α, and the angle to the blue line?

To be clear: All that is known are the angles θ and α, and the percentage along the path from B to C that the blue line intersects the line segment BC.

[image]

Comment: It is not clear what is given. If you have a triangle defined (i.e. know all sides) then it's enough to have angle between BD and the blue line to calculate what your need.

Comment: @Vasili I've updated the post to include what is given. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $E$ and $F$ be the intersection points of the "blue" line with $BC$ and $BD$, respectively.

Assume $\frac{BE}{BC}=p$, $\frac{CD}{CA}=\mu$, $\frac{EF}{EA}=\lambda$.

From
$$
\vec{BF}=x\vec{BD}
$$
we have:
$$
(1-\lambda)\, p\vec{BC}+\lambda\,\vec{BA}=x\left[(1-\mu)\,\vec{BC}+\mu\,\vec{BA}\right].
$$

It follows:
$$
\frac{1-\lambda}{1-\mu}p=\frac{\lambda}{\mu}
\implies\frac1\lambda=\frac1p\left(\frac1\mu-1\right)+1
$$

so that $x$ in question is:
$$
x=\frac\lambda\mu=\frac p{1-\mu(1-p)}.\tag1
$$

It remains only to find $\mu$ from the given angles. Realizing that $\angle CBD=\theta$ one easily finds:
$$
\mu=\frac{a\sin\theta}{a\sin\theta+c\sin(B-\theta)}.
$$
Substituting
$$
B=\frac\pi2-(\alpha-\theta)
$$
one finally obtains:
$$
\mu=\frac{a\sin\theta}{a\sin\theta+c\cos\alpha},\tag2
$$
which is to substitute into $(1)$.

The conclusion is that $p,\alpha,\theta$ are not sufficient to evaluate $x$. One needs additionally the value of $\frac ca $. It can be easily found if for example the angle $\phi=\angle BAE $ is given.

Comment: I'm able to follow your answer through your equation (1). If I know the horizontal 0° distance from A to the point intersecting BC, I'm then able to calculate AD, AC, and thus CD. Then, your equation for x seems to pan out. So, although I don't follow you after (1), your answer seems to be correct. Thanks!